# Timeout Error Woocommerce Products Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to fetch all my products using the woocommerce short code. There are around 70 products.

```
do_shortcode( '[products category="'.$a.'"]);
```

But this results in a timeout error. Is there any workaround to overcome the timeout error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can increase time limit like this max_execution_time = 800; in php.ini file and add set_time_limit(800); in wp-config.php file.